# How do I truncate a string, add the value to an Array, and delete the value?

Tags: java, string, loops, hex, truncate

I'm working on a converter in Java that would convert ASCII values to RGB. My specific problem arises when I try to truncate the Hex data. Basically, I want to create a system that would loop through the data, convert it into 6 digit blocks, and add it to an Array. While creating a separate String for the extra data. Here's my code:

```
package converter;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ASCIItoRGB{
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // Input
        String asciiValue = "2121876";

        char[] c = asciiValue.toCharArray();
        StringBuffer hexValue = new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0; i<c.length; i++) {
            hexValue.append(Integer.toHexString((int)c[i]));
        }
        String hexString = hexValue.toString();

        String hexTruncated = hexValue.toString();

        ArrayList rgbValues = new ArrayList();
        for(int i=0; i<hexString.length(); i++) {
            if(hexTruncated.length() >= 6) {
                String tempval = hexTruncated.substring(0, 5);
                rgbValues.add(Color.decode(tempval));
                tempval = hexTruncated.substring(tempval.length(), 5);
            }
            else {
            }
        }
        // Output
        System.out.println("ASCII VALUE: " + asciiValue);
        System.out.println("CHAR ARRAY: " + Arrays.toString(c));
        System.out.println("HEX VALUE: " + hexString);
        System.out.println("RGB VALUES: " + rgbValues.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: The main problem is that you assign the rest of the string to `tempval` instead of `hexTruncated`. But the whole second for loop is dodgy. Think it through again.

Comment: Okay, I'll try again.

Comment: Ok. I got it to work by using a while loop instead of a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I got it to work by using a while loop. I also changed `tempval` to equal a substring of `hexString` using the legnth of itself, and the legnth of `hexString`.

```
        // ASCII to Hex
        char[] c = asciiValue.toCharArray();
        StringBuffer hexValue = new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0; i<c.length; i++) {
            hexValue.append(Integer.toHexString((int)c[i]));
        }
        String hexString = hexValue.toString();

        // Hex to RGB
        ArrayList<Color> rgbValues = new ArrayList<Color>();
        while(hexString.length() >= 6) {
            String tempval = hexString.substring(0,6);
            rgbValues.add(Color.decode(tempval));
            hexString = hexString.substring(tempval.length(), hexString.length());
            if(hexString.length() < 6) {
                String hexExtra = hexString;
                System.out.println("EXTRA DATA: " + hexExtra);
            }
        }
```